# How to listen to local FM/AM radio broadcasts in Linux?

Tags: linux, application, multimedia

Is there any package/command that lets me listen to FM/AM radio broadcasts in my town? All the apps that I find are for streaming internet radio and not offline radio.

Comment: Removing all the unrelated tags! Please make sure you only use the tags that unambigously apply to your question.

Answer (score 4):

There are, but you’ll need radio hardware of some kind.

Many TV cards include a radio, and if a corresponding driver is available in the kernel, you can listen to AM/FM stations using a tool such as [xawtv’s `radio`](https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Radio). Similar tools are also available for DVB radio.

A more convenient solution nowadays is to use a [RTL-based software-defined radio](https://www.besthamradio.com/best-cheap-rtl-sdr-radio-kits/), and tools such as [gqrx](https://gqrx.dk/) or [CubicSDR](https://cubicsdr.com/). With this you can listen to AM/FM stations, DAB stations etc.

Comment: For DAB+ reception with an RTL-SDR dongle, I recommend Welle.io, which is a nice Qt-based GUI, which especially my father appreciates more than his kitchen radio.